# how to increment counter value in different functions in shell script

Tags: shell

i have 5 functions ..if one function works count value should be incremented and that value should be given to next function

```
count=0
function_1() { 

count++

}

function_2(){
 count++
}
```

If  function_1() works my count should be 1 and if  function_2() works means count should be 2 .If  function_1() fails , count should become 2 in function_2()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `(( .. ))`:

```
count=0

function_1() { 
   ((count++))
}

function_2(){
   ((count++))
}
```